# Escaping characters in bash alias

Tags: linux, unix, bash, aliases

This was the alias:

```
     # make a tmux session in working dir with the name of the dir
     alias th='tmux new -s $(pwd | tr '\/' '\n' | tail -n 1)'
```

It doesn't work because of the escape characters or due to the `'`, single quotes,  inside the alias. Printing it out

```
    $ type --all th
    th is aliased to `tmux new -s $(pwd | tr / n | tail -n 1)'
```

It looks like it was just stripping out the `'` and `\`.

I eventually fixed it by changing the single quotes to double quotes.

```
     # make a tmux session in working dir with the name of the dir
     alias th='tmux new -s $(pwd | tr "\/" "\n" | tail -n 1)'
```

My question is how did the previous on work at all? Shouldn't bash throw a parsing error.

Comment: Doesn't really answer your question but since you tagged bash, I'd swap `$(pwd | ...)` for `"${PWD##*/}"`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111063/bash-alias-command-with-both-single-and-double-quotes/20111135, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814087/escaping-single-quotes-inside-an-alias-in-bash

Comment: BTW, while **usually** `echo` is a very poor choice of debugging tool (with several means of munging the data it's intended to display as-is), it actually suffices to show the problem here: You'll see that `echo 'tmux new -s $(pwd | tr '\/' '\n' | tail -n 1)' ` doesn't display any inner quotes, because -- with those quotes being syntactic rather than literal -- they were consumed during the parsing process.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### Best Advice: Don't.

Use a function instead:

```
th() { tmux new -s "${PWD##*/}" "$@"; }
```

`${PWD##*/}` is a [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) which strips everything up to and including the last `/` from the contents of `$PWD`.

---

#### Alternate Approach: *Literal* Quotes

The issue in your original code is that it contains *syntactic* quotes -- ones parsed by the shell to determine where single-quoted parsing rules begin and end -- in places where what you actually want is *literal* quotes, ones which are treated as data (and thus become part of the alias).

One way to make these quotes literal would be to use the `$''` quoting form instead, which lets you use literal backslashes to escape inner quotes, making them literal rather than syntactic:

```
alias th=$'tmux new -s $(pwd | tr \'\\\/\' \'\\n\' | tail -n 1)'
```

Note that when using `$''`, literal backslashes need to be escaped as well (thus, written as `\\` rather than `\`).

---

#### Explanation: **Why**

The quoting of strings in POSIX shell languages is determined on a character-by-character basis. Thus, in the case of:

```
'$foo'"$((1+1))"baz
```

...`$foo` is single-quoted and thus treated as a literal string, `$((1+1))` is double-quoted and thus eligible for being treated as arithmetic expansion, and `baz` is unquoted -- even though all three of these are concatenated to form a single word (`$foo2baz`).

These quotes are all *syntactic* -- they're instructions to the shell -- not *literal* (which would mean they'd be part of the data to which that string evaluates).

---

#### How This Applies To Your Previous Command

In

```
alias th='tmux new -s $(pwd | tr '\/' '\n' | tail -n 1)'
```

...the single quotes in the arguments to `tr` *end* the single quotes started at the beginning of the alias. Thus, `\/` and `\n` are evaluated in an unquoted context (in which `\/` becomes just `/`, and `\n` becomes just `n`) -- and since, as described above, multiple differently-quoted substrings can just be concatenated into a single larger string, you get your prior command, not an alias.

Answer (score 2):

Your embedded single quotes weren't being treated as embedded, they were terminating previous strings and staring new ones.  Your first attempt was being treated as the concatenation of `tmux new -s $(pwd | tr`, `\/`, ' ', `\n`, and `| tail -n 1)`.  Put those all together and handle the escapes and you get what you see in the output of your `type` command.

Also worth considering: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/in-bash-when-to-alias-when-to-script-and-when-to-write-a-function

Comment: So a bash alias will just concatenate strings until an end line? To me that's unintuitive. Thanks for clearing things up.

Comment: @JohnStone well, crucially here, there are no tokenizing spaces (I actually left the space out of the list of strings accidentally).  If you had unescaped/quoted spaces anywhere in the list, those would be processed as different "words" by bash, here you just have a single word because you have a continuous string in which some parts are quoted, and some are bare strings (like `\n` for example)

Comment: @JohnStone, ...not just "a bash alias" -- *all* strings in POSIX-compliant shell languages (not just bash) follow that same rule.